# LDAP Python query and converting the appropriate dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, ldap

Sorry, I couldn't think of a better title for my question.

So I'm a starter at Python and I really trying to learn how to use it. My current problem deals with creating a simple way to reduce the results received from a python query.

If I understand what I'm dealing with, the LDAP query returns a `List` of a `List` of `Dictionary` where value in the `Dictionary` is a `List`. That's a lotta stuff there to traverse through so I figured there has to be a nice magical python way to convert this to a `List` of a `Dictionary` where the value of the `Dictionary` is just a simple string.

Currently, my code just simply to get the `List` of `Dictionary` but I still have the `Dictionary` values as a `List` themselves

```
for item in data:
    results.append(item[1])
```

Once again, I'm a beginner so I don't really understand what to do from there. I'm also using Django if that's gonna help anyone understand my plight.

**Edit (added data example):**

The Structure is kinda like this:

```
data[index][1] = {'uid': ['restest'], 'mail': [''], 'givenName': ['Research'], 'cn': ['Research Test Account'], 'sn': ['Account']}
```

I'd like it to be instead of `'givenName': ['Research']` to be `'givenName': 'Reaseach'`

Comment: Can you post some samples for what the data looks like? E.g., what the lists and dictionaries look like?

Comment: The Structure is kinda like this:

    data[index][1] = {'uid': ['restest'], 'mail': [''], 'givenName': ['Research'], 'cn': ['Research Test Account'], 'sn': ['Account']}

I'd like it to be instead of 'givenName': ['Research'] to be 'givenName': 'Reaseach'

Does that help any? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha I'm not sure you ever want such a complicated data structure around. Consider refactoring your code to make your data structures easier to understand. Read: object-oriented programming, classes, functional programming principles.

Here's the answer if you just want to do it for a single dictionary:

```
data = {k:v[0] for (k,v) in data.items()}
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> data = {'uid': ['restest'], 'mail': [''], 'givenName': ['Research'], 'cn': ['Research Test Account'], 'sn': ['Account']}
>>> data
{'mail': [''], 'sn': ['Account'], 'givenName': ['Research'], 'uid': ['restest'], 'cn': ['Research Test Account']}
>>> data = {k:v[0] for (k,v) in data.items()}
>>> data
{'mail': '', 'givenName': 'Research', 'cn': 'Research Test Account', 'sn': 'Account', 'uid': 'restest'}
```

All you're doing is re-mapping your dictionary to the first item of each list. If you want to iterate through all the levels of your structure and do this, just nest the above inside some list comprehensions:

```
[[[{k:v[0] for (k,v) in change_dict.items()} for change_dict in list_of_dicts]
  for list_of_dicts in list_of_lists]
 for list_of_lists in mydata]
```

It's not so bad to nest so many list comprehensions when you're only doing something to a "leaf" element in your data, but this is gonna get really messy if you try to manipulate your data structures at every level. See my comment at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, I keep hearing about "thinking like a python programmer" but I mostly do Java and Android development. Your solution is very concise, I was just very frustrated at the way LDAP returns their queries; normally I would try to avoid such a nested mess as this. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Bob: Yeah I never used LDAP or Django so I don't know how much of this (if any) is your fault. There could very well be an easier way to do this if you look through the LDAP documentation.